# Establish an ordering among three elements

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, lattice-orders

Consider the following expressions
$$
\begin{align}
x_1&\equiv \alpha^2 p+(1-\alpha)^2(1-p),  \\
x_2&\equiv \alpha(1-\alpha) ,\\
x_3&\equiv (1-\alpha)^2 p+\alpha^2(1-p),\\
\end{align}
$$
where $\alpha\in (1/2,1]$ and $p\in [0,1]$. Is it possible to establish an ordering among $x_1, x_2, x_3$? It is assumed that $x_1\in (0,1)$,  $x_2\in (0,1)$, $x_3\in (0,1)$.

So far, I have tried to answer this question by attempting to solve the inequalities
$$
x_1\geq (\text{ or, }\leq \text{ }) x_2\\
x_1\geq (\text{ or, }\leq \text{ }) x_3\\
x_2\geq (\text{ or, }\leq \text{ }) x_3\\
$$
but I did not go far because I end up with complicated expressions. I'm wondering whether there may be a smarter way to solve this exercise. Could you advise?

Comment: $x_2$ simplifies to $\alpha(1-\alpha)$  Is this a typo?

Comment: No, it is correct that  $x_2=\alpha(1-\alpha)$. I have added that. Thanks

Comment: Have you taken calculus yet?

Comment: Not yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this is to think of $\alpha$ as fixed and $p$ as varying.  Since $\frac12<\alpha\leq1$, we know that $\alpha>1-\alpha$, and consequently that $$(1-\alpha)^2<\alpha(1-\alpha)<\alpha^2$$

The middle term in this inequality is, of course, $x_2$.  Now, when $p=0$, we have $x_1=(1-\alpha)^2,\ x_3=\alpha^2$ so that $$x_1<x_2<x_3.$$  When $p=1$, we have $x_1=\alpha^2,\ x_3=(1-\alpha)^2$ so that $$x_3<x_2<x_1.$$

Therefore, no order can be established among the three expressions.